# Using sed to remove digit separation commas enclosed in quotes and quotes itself from CSV?

Tags: sed, regular-expression

How can I can use sed to remove from before-last column the group digit char comma and quotes itself?

Please note that in the sample below the target column is not contained in double quotes.

```
0,1,,,"10,815,197",
6,7,010202,,"5,589",
6,7,010202,,589,
```

An expetect result would be:

```
0,1,,,10815197,
6,7,010202,,5589,
6,7,010202,,589,
```

Comment: Could you post your expected output?

Comment: is your input always contain digits and commas?

Answer (score 2):

`Awk` will be the best for your scenario.

```
$ awk -F'"' '{gsub(",", "", $2);print}' file.txt 
0,1,,, 10815197 ,
6,7,010202,, 5589 ,
6,7,010202,,589,
```

***How it works***

`-F'"'`          - causes `AWK` to use double quotes ( " ) as record separator.

`gsub(",","",$2)` - `gsub` function will search and replace all occurrence of double quotes with empty string.

`print`          - It prints the modified content to the output.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's easier with `awk`. You can try something like this:

```
$ awk -v v='"' 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=v}{gsub(",","",$2);gsub("\"","",$0);print }' file.txt
0,1,,,10815197,
6,7,010202,,5589,
6,7,010202,,589,
```

- Basically you are telling `awk` that use a regular expression `-v v='"'` to use it as field separator.
- With `FS=OFS=v` you say that the field separator is the same as output field separator which is the `"`.
- `gsub (",","",$2)` replace the `,` with nothing on the second field `$2` (delimited in the start and the end with `"`).
- `gsub("\"","",$0)` takes the whole line and replace `"` with nothing before the printout of the line.

Answer (score 0):

sed is not the right tool for this.

```
$ perl -pe 's|"([\d,]+)"(?=[^"]*$)|$1=~y/,//dr|eg' file
0,1,,,10815197,
6,7,010202,,5589,
6,7,010202,,589,
```

Through Python.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import sys
import re
file = sys.argv[1]
with open(file, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        print(re.sub(r'"([\d,]+)"(?=[^"]*$)', lambda m: m.group(1).replace(',', ''), line), end = "")
```

Save the above script to a file , say `script.py` and run then run the sript by firing the below command on the terminal.

```
$ python3 script.py inputfile
```